# How to change the console font size

Tags: c++, winapi, console, font-size

How can I change the font size in a console app on Windows? Simplest way?
What is the difference between changing console color using `system("")` and windows.h?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can change the font size using `SetCurrentConsoleFontEx`.
 Below is a small example that you can play around with, make sure you `#include <cwchar>` and `#include <windows.h>`

```
CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX cfi;
cfi.cbSize = sizeof(cfi);
cfi.nFont = 0;
cfi.dwFontSize.X = 0;                   // Width of each character in the font
cfi.dwFontSize.Y = 24;                  // Height
cfi.FontFamily = FF_DONTCARE;
cfi.FontWeight = FW_NORMAL;
std::wcscpy(cfi.FaceName, L"Consolas"); // Choose your font
SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FALSE, &cfi);

std::cout << "Font: Consolas, Size: 24\n";
```

If you choose *Arial* or others, you may have to give it a font size width. For more [information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682069(v=vs.85).aspx).

---

The difference between `system()` calls and using `Windows.h` is that `system()` calls are resource heavy and unsafe. More information [here.](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/11153/)

Comment: *"If you choose Arial or others"* - which ones? *"[...] you may have to give it a font size width."* - under what conditions?

Comment: Maybe worth noting that `SetCurrentConsoleFontEx` requires Vista or later ( _WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0500). Also, the documentation is not clear on how exactly `cfi.nFont = 0;` works ("*nFont = The index of the font in the system's console font table.*").

Comment: any chance you know how to do this on Ubuntu?