# I've found this code to change the font but it doesn't work

Tags: c++, winapi, fonts

I've just found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35382432/how-to-change-the-console-font-size) answer to change the console font and size. But it didn't work: Either the font stays at `Consolas` or changes to `Courier new`. I would like to use `Lucida Sans Typewriter`.

```
CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX cfi{};
    cfi.cbSize = sizeof(cfi);
    cfi.nFont = 0;
    cfi.dwFontSize.X = 0;                   // Width of each character in the font
    cfi.dwFontSize.Y = 19;                  // Height
    cfi.FontFamily = FF_DONTCARE;
    cfi.FontWeight = FW_NORMAL;
    std::wcscpy(cfi.FaceName, L"Lucida Sans Typewriter"); // Choose your font
    SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FALSE, &cfi);
```

Comment: Did you call `GetLastError`, as the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setcurrentconsolefontex) states you should use if the return value is 0?

Comment: Pro tip: It's rarely a good idea to copy some code, without actually understanding what it does completely. That's why there exists documentation for such API functions.

Comment: I just wrote ```DWORD Last_Error =  GetLastError();``` but the function's return value ist 0, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug that hasn't been fixed yet. If the font name contains more than 16 characters it won't be set through the API (but it works from the console).
The call to SetCurrentConsoleFontEx() returns success regardless of if the specified font was set or not.

Read more here:
https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/258